# How can I pin an access database file to the user's taskbar?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having trouble finding anything useful online regarding this question. Can someone point me in the right direction? Here is what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit


'Const CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS = &H17
Dim ShellApp, FSO, Desktop
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Set StartMenuFolder = ShellApp.NameSpace(CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS)
Set Desktop =  ShellApp.NameSpace("C:\Users\myUser\Desktop")

Dim LnkFile
LnkFile = Desktop.Self.Path & "\myTest.lnk"

If(FSO.FileExists(LnkFile)) Then
    Dim tmp, verb
    'For Each verb in Desktop.ParseName("myTest.lnk").Verbs
        'tmp = tmp&verb&chr(13)
    'Next
    'MsgBox(tmp)

    Dim desktopImtes, item
    Set desktopImtes = Desktop.Items()

    For Each item in desktopImtes
        If (item.Name = "myTest") Then
            'MsgBox(item.Name)
            For Each verb in item.Verbs
                If (verb.Name = "Pin to Tas&kbar") Then
                    verb.DoIt
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

End If

Set FSO = Nothing
Set ShellApp = Nothing
```

When I go through each `verb.name`, `"Pin to Tas&kbar"` never shows up. Is this a known issue?

Edit: Here is my second attempt:

```
Dim objShell, objAllUsersProgramsFolder, strAllUsersProgramsPath, objFolder, objFolderItem, colVerbs, objVerb
Const CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS = &H17
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objAllUsersProgramsFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:\Users\myUser\Desktop")
strAllUsersProgramsPath = objAllUsersProgramsFolder.Self.Path
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strAllUsersProgramsPath)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("myTest.lnk")
Set objVerb = objFolderItem.Verbs '''!! this line is where it fails !!'''
For Each objVerb In colVerbs
    If Replace(objVerb.Name, "&", "") = "Pin to Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
Next
```

The line marked shows where the error is located. The error states:

`Object variable or With block variable not set.`

It may help to note that the link is pointing to an access database.

Comment: Not sure why your first attempt is failing - perhaps add at breakpoint and watch on the item.Verbs and look at individual items. In the second attempt you've defined all your variables as variants - it looks like they are meant to be a combination of strings, variants and objects. `Dim objShell, objAllUsersProgramsFolder, strAllUsersProgramsPath, objFolder, objFolderItem, colVerbs, objVerb` - use separate line for each item to be sure you've DIMmed them correctly

Comment: @dbmitch I tried that and "Pin to Tas&kbar" does not show up.

Comment: Does "Pin to Taskbar" show up if you do right-click on your shortcut?

Comment: @dbmitch No it doesn't!

Comment: Is the shortcut on a network folder? What is the title text of the shortcut? Some values are supposedly not allowed - these are stored in registry setting: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileAssociation\AddRemoveNames`

Comment: @dbmitch No, the title text is "myTest.lnk". I don't know what to do with the registry setting link you gave me - how should I use that?

Comment: Probably not an issue in your case

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is a common one - code is being copied/pasted from a Google Search result without an attempt to understand it - or even do basic troublsehooting to determine if it works - or how it's supposed to work.

What you've done is to copy directly from [this codeproject url](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185512/Programmatically-PIN-shortcut-onto-Taskbar-on-Win) or some other site that copied/pasted this code. The commented out code is still intact exactly as is.

It looks like you did the same thing in the second attempt too, but I won't even look at that one as it's a half attempt with same basic errors

The biggest issue with both code samples is that:

- Variables are dimmed as variants - when the important ones are
  objects.

The biggest issue with ***your*** attempt is:

- You've done no debugging or troubleshooting with debug statements.

I've cleaned up this sub with variable declarations and debug code to identify how where your code might be failing. Change the constants at the top to match your user and file name - make sure you rightclick on your shortcut and look at the properties to make sure your path is correct.

**Try this and hopefully the msgbox and debug statements will point to your problem. I assume it will be a simple path or filename error.**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PinApp()

    Const DESKTOP_USER      As String = "Public" ' username shown in file properties
    Const SHORTCUT_FILE     As String = "My Shortcut"

    Dim objShellApp         As Object ' Shell Application
    Dim objFSO              As Object ' FileSystemObject
    Dim objDesktop          As Object ' Folder
    Dim objDesktopItems     As Object

    Dim varVerb             As Variant
    Dim varItem             As Variant

    Dim strShortcut         As String

    Dim blFound             As Boolean
    Dim blPinned            As Boolean

    Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set objDesktop = objShellApp.NameSpace("C:\Users\" & DESKTOP_USER & "\Desktop")

    strShortcut = objDesktop.Self.Path & "\" & SHORTCUT_FILE & ".lnk"

    blFound = False
    blPinned = False

    ' Check first to see if Shortcut File exists
    If (objFSO.FileExists(strShortcut)) Then

        Set objDesktopItems = objDesktop.Items()

        For Each varItem In objDesktopItems

            If (varItem.Name = SHORTCUT_FILE) Then
Debug.Print "Found Shortcut"
                blFound = True
                For Each varVerb In varItem.Verbs
Debug.Print varVerb.Name
                    If (varVerb.Name = "Pin to Tas&kbar") Then
                        varVerb.DoIt
                        blPinned = True
                        ' no sense continuing - we found what we're looking for
                        MsgBox "Shortcut File Pinned"
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                ' no sense continuing - we found what we're looking for
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If Not blFound Then
            MsgBox "Shortcut File Not Found in Desktop Items: " & strShortcut
        ElseIf Not blPinned Then
            MsgBox "Failed to find Pin To Taskbar"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Missing Shortcut File: " & strShortcut
    End If

    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objShellApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Although you're right that I copied/pasted the code, it still worked the same as yours. When I go to print each verb name, there is no "Pin to Tas&kbar".

Comment: so you got message that it failed to find pin to taskbar? What is listed in your target?